Editable columns with Soft Deleted models
I try to find out how to works with soft deleted models and editable columns.
I found the beginning of solution when I override saveMinorUpdateEntry function like that :
    public function saveMinorUpdateEntry()
    {
        $entry = $this->crud->getModel()->withTrashed()->find(request('id'));
        $entry->{request('attribute')} = request('value');
        
        return $entry->save();
    }


BUT, it seems when the ajax request is performed, this function is called because the update is done.
And after, another action is performed with this function :
    /**

     * Setup operation default settings.

     */

    public function saveMinorUpdate()

    {

        $this->setupListOperation();



        CRUD::hasAccessOrFail('list');



        $this->minorUpdateRequest = CRUD::getRequest();

        $this->minorUpdateEntry = CRUD::getModel()->findOrFail($this->minorUpdateRequest->id);



        // Validate request

        $this->saveMinorUpdateFormValidation();



        // Update entry

        $this->minorUpdateEntry = $this->saveMinorUpdateEntry();



        return [

            'saved' => $this->minorUpdateEntry,

            'row' => $this->getMinorUpdateRow(),

        ];

    }

And for this part, I have an error message Call to a member function withFakes() on bool. It's normal because         $this->minorUpdateEntry = CRUD::getModel()->findOrFail($this->minorUpdateRequest->id); don't call with withTrashed() directive.
Anyone know how to allow softDeleting editable column update, without override all this code ?
Thanks,

I forward on this problem.
The process works with this code in my CrudController :
    public function saveMinorUpdate()
    {
        $this->setupListOperation();
        
        CRUD::hasAccessOrFail('list');

        $this->minorUpdateRequest = CRUD::getRequest();
        $this->minorUpdateEntry = CRUD::getModel()->withTrashed()->findOrFail($this->minorUpdateRequest->id);
    
        // Validate request
        $this->saveMinorUpdateFormValidation();

        // Update entry
        $this->minorUpdateEntry = $this->saveMinorUpdateEntry();

        return [
            'saved' => $this->minorUpdateEntry,
            'row' => $this->getMinorUpdateRow(),
        ];
    }
 

    public function saveMinorUpdateEntry()
    {
        $this->minorUpdateEntry->{request('attribute')} = request('value');

        $this->minorUpdateEntry->save();
        return $this->minorUpdateEntry->refresh();
    }

But it seems backpack don't have this feature instead.
